# ¿Como agregar un div y no remplazarlo?

Tags: javascript, html5, base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy realizando una aplicacion web en la que se mostraran unas tarjetas con información sobre un producto.

La información la obtengo de realtime database de firebase, entonces la información que obtengo es un objeto json de el cual obtengo la longitud y así obtengo la cantidad de tarjetas a mostrar mediante un for hago que se agreguen los div necesarios, pero estos no se agregan si no que se remplazan.

Les muestro mi codigo

```js
function GetInfoProduct(){

  let PathLengthCardsProducts;

  PathLengthCardsProducts = "/Productos";

  firebase.database().ref(PathLengthCardsProducts).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let Datagetted, DatagettedLength;
    if(snapshot.val()){

      Datagetted = snapshot.val();

      DatagettedLength = Datagetted.length;

      console.log(DatagettedLength);
      console.log('----------------');
      console.log(Datagetted);
      
      let ProductsCards;

      ProductsCards = document.getElementById('ContenedorDeTarjetas');

      let CardProduct = `
        <div class="product_card"></div>
      `;

      for(let i = 0; i <DatagettedLength; i++){

        ProductsCards.innerHTML = CardProduct;
        console.log("Card " + i + " creada")

        console.log("tarjeta" + i);
      }


    }
  })

}
```

espero me puedan ayudar con este problema; De ante mano Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProductsCards.innerHTML = CardProduct
```

Cada vez que el programa hace eso, asigna un nuevo valor a la variable innerHTML. No soy ningún profesional, pero puedes probar, aunque seguramente sea un poco feo o esté mal, con esto:

```
ProductsCards.innerHTML = ProductsCards.innerHTML + " " + CardProduct
```

Edit: Como me han comentado, innerHTML no es una variable, así que quizá podrías almacenar las iteraciones en una variable y después asignar el innerHTML el valor de esa variable:

```
let texto;
for(let i = 0; i <DatagettedLength; i++){

        texto = texto + " " + CardProduct;
        console.log("Card " + i + " creada")

        console.log("tarjeta" + i);
}
ProductsCards.innerHTML = texto
```

Comment: innerHTML no es una variable, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML